# SQL plus join query with calculations

Tags: sql, oracle

I the following tables in my data base.

Party:

```
Column Name Data Type   Nullable    Default Primary Key
PARTY_ID    NUMBER  No  -   1
PARTY_DESC  VARCHAR2(200)   No  -   -
PARTY_CREDIT_LIMIT  NUMBER  No  -   -
PARTY_STATUS    NUMBER  No  -   -
PARTY_ADDRESS   VARCHAR2(200)   No  -   -
PARTY_OFFICE    VARCHAR2(12)    Yes -   -
PARTY_CELLPHONE VARCHAR2(12)    Yes -   -
PARTY_RESIDENCE VARCHAR2(12)    Yes -   -
PARTY_DUE_DATE_LIMIT    NUMBER  No  -   -
PARTY_CURRENT_BALANCE   NUMBER  Yes 0   -
PARTY_PROFIT_GAINED NUMBER  Yes 0   -
PARTY_TURNOVER  NUMBER  Yes 0   -
CITY_ID NUMBER  No  -   -
PARTY_OPENING_BAL   NUMBER  Yes -   -
```

Purchase:

```
PURCHASE_ID NUMBER  No  -   1
PARTY_ID    NUMBER  No  -   -
U_NAME  VARCHAR2(50)    No  -   -
PURCHASE_DISCOUNT_RS    NUMBER  Yes 0   -
PURCHASE_DISCOUNT_P NUMBER  Yes 0   -
PURCHASE_FREIGHT    NUMBER  Yes 0   -
PURCHASE_LUMPSUM_DISCOUNT   NUMBER  Yes 0   -
PURCHASE_GROSS_VALUE    NUMBER  No  -   -
PURCHASE_NET_INVOICE_VALUE  NUMBER  No  -   -
PURCHASE_DATE   TIMESTAMP(6)    Yes systimestamp    -
```

Sale:

```
SALE_ID NUMBER  No  -   1
PARTY_ID    NUMBER  No  -   -
U_NAME  VARCHAR2(50)    No  -   -
SALE_DISCOUNT_RS    NUMBER  Yes 0   -
SALE_DISCOUNT_P NUMBER  Yes 0   -
SALE_FREIGHT    NUMBER  Yes 0   -
SALE_CARTONS    NUMBER  Yes 0   -
SALE_CARTON_RATE    NUMBER  Yes 0   -
SALE_BOX    NUMBER  Yes 0   -
SALE_BOX_RATE   NUMBER  Yes 0   -
SALE_LUMPSUM_DISCOUNT   NUMBER  Yes 0   -
SALE_GROSS_VALUE    NUMBER  Yes -   -
SALE_GROSS_INVOICE_VALUE    NUMBER  Yes -   -
SALE_NET_INVOICE_VALUE  NUMBER  Yes -   -
SALE_DATE   TIMESTAMP(6)    Yes systimestamp    -
```

And I want a query which results in some thing like this:

```
date         ,   desc              , Tr No. , Debit  , Credit  , Balance
01/06/2010   ,   opening balance   ,        ,        ,         , 720
02/06/2010   ,   Sale              , 23     , 170    ,         , 890
03/06/2010   ,   Purchase          , 54     ,        ,  100    , 790
30/06/2010   ,   closing balance   ,        ,        ,         , 790
```

I dont know how to do the calculations made in last column. And how to get both purchase and sale columns in a single column.

Comment: Please show the query that works for all the other columns (by editing your question).

Comment: actually i havent created that one yet ..
i am very confused.
I am thinking of creating a temporary table, inserting data from purchase and sale into temporary table and then run the query to have result like above ..

Comment: You state:  "I don't know how to do the calculations made in last column. ".  As a casual reader, this implies that you do know how to get the first five columns, and that would be a help for anyone attempting to answer this.

Comment: Especially because I'm rather curious how you're getting the `desc` column in your output - there doesn't seem to be a source column.  Nor is there a unified `Tr No.` between your sale/purchase tables (or is that supposed to be a _count_?).  Or if your `closing balance` row is supposed to be auto-generated or what.  Or what numbers to use to calculate the `debit`/`credit` columns.  Difficult to tell what you're expecting to be done without starting data, and you could at least show us what you've got so far.  Then we start getting towards edge cases (like concurrent sales/purchases)...

Comment: i have created a table transaction which has columns date,  description, debit, credit and tr no..
I have written triggers on purchase and sale table which insert data in transaction table .. now i am able to get first four columns except the opening and closing balance row ..